# ans ns =[(j, k) for j, k in (self.x_values, self.y_values) ] NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, pygal

I want use pygal to paint random rambled points
and stored a svg file
  in  run.py i are try use loop , every loop 1 times make some data, and assignment a variables
my code:
random_walk.py

```
from random import choice
class RandomWalk():
    def __init__(self, num_points=10240):
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:    
            x_direction = choice([1, -1])
            x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance
            y_direction = choice([1, -1])
            y_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

            self.x_values.append(next_x)
            self.y_values.append(next_y)
```

run.py

```
import pygal
from random_walk import RandomWalk

xy_sjmb = pygal.XY(stroke=False)
xy_sjmb.title = "random rambled"

a, b, c, d = [], [], [], []
all =[a, b, c, d]
for i in range(len(all)):
    rw = RandomWalk()
    rw.fill_walk()    
    ns =[(j, k)  for j, k in (self.x_values, self.y_values) ]
    all[i-1] = ns

xy_sjmb.add('a', a)
xy_sjmb.add('b', b)
xy_sjmb.add('c', c)
xy_sjmb.add('d', d)
xy_sjmb.render_to_file('sjmb.svg')
```

but have  error :
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Change `ns =[(j, k)  for j, k in (self.x_values, self.y_values) ]` to `ns =[(j, k)  for j, k in (rw.x_values, rw.y_values) ]`.

`self` is used to refer to an object from inside that object. But externally you need to refer to the object with a variable that points to it.